# For-in loop in TypeScript always treats variable like a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is something that has been bugging me for a while now. In TypeScript, if I define a for-in loop my variable is always treated as a string. Example:

```
for(var room in this.rooms) {
    room.placement.x = 52;
}
```

The `room.placement.x` will fail because it treats `room` as a string. `this.rooms` is actually a collection of Room objects, but room is not a Room... it's a string.

Is this a TypeScript version issue or something that is sticking around? It's highly frustrating.

Is there a way to define room so that TypeScript can treat it like a Room?

The definition of rooms is: `private rooms: Room.Game.Room[];`

It's an array of custom objects.

Comment: Why you use `for..in` with array? use `.map` instead.

Comment: while this may be a duplicate question, the answer provided by Bruno is unique and is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `this.rooms` is an array, the proper syntax is `for ...of`:

```
for (let room of this.rooms) {
    room.placement.x = 52;
}
```

`for ... in`  iterates over the keys.

See [this](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/for...of) for more.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I will accept your answer when the timer lets me.